# Remix error while running the following Inherited Solidity Model

Tags: solidity, blockchain, contract-design

UPDATED BELOW: (What worked for Me)

While compiling and running the following code on Remix.   When I try to initialize Master with _ownerName, I get the following error  "This contract does not implement all functions and thus cannot be created".

I wanted to create new Customer Contracts using the CustomerTemplate Contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
//----- Templates 
//----- 
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

contract CustomerTemplate {

    bytes32 public customerName;
    bytes32 public customerLoc;

    function CustomerTemplate (bytes32 _customerName, bytes32 _customerLoc)  {

        customerName    = _customerName;
        customerLoc     = _customerLoc;

    }

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
//----- Master 
//----- Initialize Customer Master with Customer Name and Total Budget
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

contract Master is CustomerTemplate{

    address public owner;
    bytes32 public ownerName;
    address[] newCustomers;

    modifier onlyByMaster()  {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function Master (bytes32 _ownerName) {

        owner = msg.sender;
        ownerName = _ownerName;
    }

    function createCustomer (bytes32 _customerName, bytes32 _customerLoc) {

        address myCustomer = new CustomerTemplate(_customerName, _customerLoc);
        newCustomers.push(myCustomer);
    }

    function killContract() constant onlyByMaster {

        if (msg.sender == owner) selfdestruct(owner);

    }

}
```

(UPDATE) The following worked for me:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;


contract Template {

    bytes32  public custName;
    bytes32  public custLoc;
    address  public contractAddress;

    function Template () {

        custName            = "0xDEFAULT";
        custLoc             = "0xDEFAULT";
        contractAddress     = address(this);

    }

    function AssignCustomerAttributes (bytes32 _custName, bytes32 _custLoc)  
        returns (bool isSuccess) {

        custName    = _custName;
        custLoc     = _custLoc;

        contractAddress  = address(this);

        return true;

    }

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
//----- Master 
//----- Initialize Customer Master with Customer Name and Total Budget
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 


pragma solidity ^0.4.15;


contract Template {

    bytes32  public custName;
    bytes32  public custLoc;
    address  public contractAddress;

    function Template () {

        custName            = "0xDEFAULT";
        custLoc             = "0xDEFAULT";
        contractAddress     = address(this);

    }

    function AssignCustomerAttributes (bytes32 _custName, bytes32 _custLoc)  
        returns (bool isSuccess) {

        custName    = _custName;
        custLoc     = _custLoc;

        contractAddress  = address(this);

        return true;

    }

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
//----- Master 
//----- Initialize Customer Master with Customer Name and Total Budget
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

contract Master {

    address  public     masterContractAddress;
    bytes32  public     masterName = "";
    Template    myCustTemp; 

    function Master () {

        masterContractAddress = address(this);

    }

    function updateOwnerName (bytes32 _masterName)  {

        masterName = _masterName;

    }

    function createCustomer (bytes32 _custName, bytes32 _custLoc)  returns (bool flag) {

        Template myCust = new Template();

        if (myCust.AssignCustomerAttributes(_custName, _custLoc)) {

            return true;

        } else return false;

    }


}
```

Comment: I think master constructor need to provide all the arguments needed to the parent class.

Comment: Hi @AchalaDissanayake, Thanks for your input.  I have yet to try it out.   I am trying to fix another issue before I test this out and provide my feedback.  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27167/solidity-debugging-in-remix

Comment: cool, good luck with your stuff :)

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake,  I provided the updated code that worked for me.   Thanks,

Comment: great that you got it working, but I see no inheritance there. the  error of the original code you posted was due to missing arguments while inheritance is used :)

Comment: @AchalaDissanayake, that is correct.   This is probably another way of doing it.  My goal was to create a Contract Factory that would systematically create new contracts.

Comment: Just as a suggestion, I don't think `contractAddress` is necessary. One would need to know the `contractAddress` to invoke the getter function. If one knows, they why ask?

Comment: @RobHitchens.  I agree.   I was trying to see the newly generated Contract from the Master to validate that it is really generating a new contract at a new address.    The long term plan is to interact with the new contracts directly (automated) from an engine that resides outside the Ethereum blockchain.  I am new to blockchain.   I am assuming that the address is the critical element to access the Contract and its elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide all the arguments needed for the parent class. From the solidity docs [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#arguments-for-base-constructors),

> Derived contracts need to provide all arguments needed for the base constructors.

So the master constructor would look like,

```
function Master (bytes32 _ownerName, bytes32 _loc) CustomerTemplate(_ownerName, _loc) {

    owner = msg.sender;
    ownerName = _ownerName;
}
```

Comment: What if the inherited contract doesn't have any constructor args?  Doing `CustomerTemplate()` still throws "This contract does not implement all functions"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. It might happen if you use inheritance.

The fix is fairly trivial. There is a drop-down near the "Create" button in Remix (aka Browser-Solidity). You just need to select the actual contract implementation to deploy, not the interface.