# Solidity Debugging in Remix

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I am working Remix Browser for the following simple Contract.   I had a couple of questions.  I could not find the right answers.

1. During Contract Creation:   It gives the following error.  What is this error.  How can I get rid of it?

> undefined errored:  cannot read property 'op' of undefined

2. I have an event defined.  Where can I see the output of the event on Remix browser?

[image: Compiler Results]

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
    contract MyContract {

        bytes32  public custName;
        bytes32  public custLoc;
        address public docAddress = this;

        function MyContract () {

            custName = "0xDEFAULT";
            custLoc  = "0xDEFAULT";

        }

        event LogNewCust (address _address, bytes32 _custName, bytes32 _custLoc);

        function AssignAttributes (bytes32 _custName, bytes32 _custLoc)  
            returns (bool isSuccess) {

            custName    = _custName;
            custLoc     = _custLoc;

            LogNewCust(docAddress,custName,custLoc);

            return true;

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Seems to be some bug, the contract is deployable without a problem.
2. When you make the event fire, you find it in the logs: [image]

Comment: Thanks for verifying the bug.    I found the logs and it is working.   Thanks.